# Searching for a string in all .txt files

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to search for a string `test123` in all textfiles on the hdd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` to get all the `.txt` files and then `grep` the desired string

```
$ find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'test123' {} +
```

Where:

- `/` search in all the server.
- `-type f` find only files, not directories
- `-name '*.txt'` find all `.txt` files
- `-exec grep 'test123'` search `test123` in all the files found
- `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone
- `+` it will improve execution time significantly (since it will contatenate arguments prior to execution until)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "all textfiles" you mean al files ending in .txt:

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -i 'test123' {} \;
```

or

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -i 'test123' {} +
```

Comment: Can you explain the differences between your solutions?

Comment: `+` is better because it doesn't run grep for every file found.

Answer (score 1):

```
find / -type f -exec grep -I test123 {} +
```

Version with `+` instead of `\;` is much faster and`-I` ignores binary files. Or simply use recursive grep:

```
grep -Ir test123 /
```

You probably also want to `2>/dev/null` because there are going to be a lot of "permission denied" lines.

Answer (score -1):

Something to point you in the right direction:

`find / -type f -name *.txt` to find all .txt files, assuming you only have one hdd. 
And then just use `grep` to search in these files.

Comment: Can you give me all commands? I am new to Linux.

Comment: Tachomis answer should work.